# Como inserir tags HTML em um array do Anguar?

Tags: angular

Boa noite!

Preciso inserir dentro de um array do Angular a tag `<sup></sup>`, pesquisei mas não encontrei solução.

No navegador esta sendo renderizado: Decreto n`<sup>`o`</sup>` 32.231, de 09.03.2020 - DOM Salvador de 10.03.20200.

Poderiam me ajudar por favor?

**app.component.html**

```
<app-act-card></app-act-card>
```

**act-card.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let i of laws">
  <p>{{i.decree}}</p>
</div>
```

**act-card.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-act-card',
  templateUrl: './act-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./act-card.component.scss']
})
export class ActCardComponent implements OnInit {

  public laws = [
    { 
      decree: 'Decreto n<sup>o</sup> 32.231, de 09.03.2020 - DOM Salvador de 10.03.20200',
    }
  ];

}
```

Comment: Não pode simplesmente usar o caractere "°" (no meu teclado é `alt gr` + `?`)?

Comment: @Costamilam, utilizar caracteres especiais diretamente em um arquivo HTML pode gerar problemas de [mapa de caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11948/165800).

Comment: @LucasSamuel só se precisar de compatibilidade com navegadores antigos ou muito ruins

Comment: Independentemente disso, não é recomendado. Na empresa em que trabalho, charset gerava problemas por conta dos diferentes SO's e navegadores utilizados por nossos usuários. Tivemos que alterar todas as acentuações para [notações compatíveis](http://www.erikasarti.com/html/acentuacao-caracteres-especiais/).

Comment: Obrigado a todos! Sei que não é uma boa prática, mas preciso entregar um mockup funcional para a equipe de backend, eles tratarão de consumir essas informações de forma correta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve usar o *[property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-targets)* do Angular para determinar o valor de uma propriedade em um elemento HTML. Como você quer determinar o HTML dentro de um elemento `p`, a propriedade [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) desse elemento deve ser definida.

No Angular, você pode definir a propriedade de um elemento HTML usando essa sintaxe: `[propriedade]`. Portanto, o seu HTML deve ficar na seguinte forma:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of laws">
  <p [innerHTML]="i.decree"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Lucas!